# "Is That" Sentence Structure

Tags: grammaticality, subordinate-clauses

> The Principle of Sound Learning **is that** the noise of vulgar fame should never trouble the cloistered calm of academic existence.

This is from a piece of edited prose. The author repeatedly uses the construction "is that" to mean something like "states that." It sounds slightly off but then I'm no native speaker. Is it ungrammatical, grammatical, or merely odd-sounding?

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. "States that" would call for a direct quote, or a close paraphrase of one, rather than a description of the Principle in the author's own words.

If I found this construction repeatedly in a document I would wish the author had taken the trouble to write more varied lively prose. (But the sentence following "is that" is eloquent.)